# Java generics wildcards: Why does this not compile?

Tags: java

```
class Demo {
    <T> void gTee(List<List<T>> tl) {
        tee(tl);
    }

    void tee(List<List<?>> tl) {
    }
}
```

JDK 8 says

`incompatible types: java.util.List<java.util.List<T>> cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.util.List<?>>`

How come? I was of the opinion that the `?` wildcard stands for *any type*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to this behaviour of Java generics:

> Even if `A` and `B` are compatible types, `SomeType<A>` is not compatible with `SomeType<B>`

A classic example of this is trying to assign a `List<Cat>` to a `List<Animal>`.

The same thing happens here. Normally, `List<T>` can be assigned to `List<?>`. But since you are assigning `List<List<T>>` to `List<List<?>>`, you can't.

Answer (score 4):

Ah. Holy cube. I should have known but it did not come to my mind:

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Use-site_variance_annotations_.28wildcards.29

It compiles now:

```
class Demo {
    <T> void gTee(List<List<T>> tl) {
        tee(tl);
    }

    void tee(List<? extends List<?>> tl) {
    }
}
```